# jQuery-validating start time and end time selected using time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to validate start time and end time selected using **timepicker** which is in 12 hr format. The end time should be greater than the start time. I used an `if` statement but when the test is using values such as 8:00 AM as start time and 1:00 PM as end time, it is not working. What can I do to solve this problem. Someone please help me with this. I am stuck with this since yesterday. I want just **time** ,i **don't need date**.

```
$("#dateTimeAddButton").click(function () 
{       
    var Date=$('#myDatePickerId').val()
    var startTime = $('#i').val();   
    var endTime   = $('#i1').val();    
    if (startTime > endTime) 
    {
        alert('End time always greater then start time.');
    }
});
```

Comment: Show your code. where is you `if` statement?

Comment: you can use 24-hr format for time. This will resolve your problem for comparing.

Comment: I cant use 24 hr format for time.I need 12 hr itself.

Comment: I am not getting when i am using localeCompare. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert to lowest denominational (minute here). Then compare it.

```
st = minFromMidnight(startTime);
et = minFromMidnight(endTime);
if(st>et){
    alert("End time must be greater than start time");
}

function minFromMidnight(tm){
 var ampm= tm.substr(-2)
 var clk = tm.substr(0, 5);
 var m  = parseInt(clk.match(/\d+$/)[0], 10);
 var h  = parseInt(clk.match(/^\d+/)[0], 10);
 h += (ampm.match(/pm/i))? 12: 0;
 return h*60+m;
}
```

Comment: I am not getting when i am using localeCompare. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Midhun I have updated to a more efficient algorithm. Its better than localeCompare solution

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I would like to know the logic behind the code..i have never used the localeCompare function.Can u just give me a brief idea about the code u have given? sorry if i am asking more from you.

Comment: The function `minFromMidnight` convert a time string such as `08:01 PM` to a number of minutes after Midnight. For `08:01 PM` it'll be `1201`  minutes. 08=8*60, 1=1*1, PM=12*60. Hence its 1201. Then you just compare this number.

Comment: kk.thnx a lot..i hv to look into it for more details..anyway thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im  this minFromMidnight() function is compare start time and end time 24-hr format  or 12-hr format plz say?

Answer (score 0):

please try that below code in case you have length of time more than 6 char like 10:00am instead of 9:00am will throw error above code.

I did minor changes in above code and it worked like charm for me.

```js
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () {
           
            var startTime = $('#txtJobStartTime').val();
            var endTime = $('#txtJobEndTime').val();
           
            var st = minFromMidnight(startTime);
            var et = minFromMidnight(endTime);
            if (st > et) {
                alert('End time always greater then start time.');
                return false;
            }

            function minFromMidnight(tm) {
                var ampm = tm.substr(-2);
                var clk;
                if (tm.length <= 6) {
                    clk = tm.substr(0, 4);
                } else {
                    clk = tm.substr(0, 5);
                }
                var m = parseInt(clk.match(/\d+$/)[0], 10);
                var h = parseInt(clk.match(/^\d+/)[0], 10);
                h += (ampm.match(/pm/i)) ? 12 : 0;
                return h * 60 + m;
            }
        });
```